# Could overriding Python destructor (__del__) cause memory leaks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, python-3.6

I have a script where I create an object over a cloud using API and want to delete it over some occasions, at the end of the script.

```
class ObjCreator():
   def __init__(self, keep_object: bool):
      self.keep_object = keep_object
      print("init")
   
   def create_object(self):
      print("Created object using API")

   def delete_object(self):
      print("Deleting object using API")

   def __del__(self):
      print("Deleting object using API only if keep_object is False")
      if not self.keep_object:
         self.delete_object()
```

I've seen some memory leaks over Python programs, so obviously the GC isn't prefect (i.e., uncollectable objects).

My fear is that overriding the **del** function would cause a memory leak.
Is that possible?
If so, do you have any suggestion to a different, elegant solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just a note, you are not _overloading_ it, you are _overriding_ it, perhaps that could help with googling an answer

Comment: Additional hint: All of these methods need the added parameter `self` to work -- this is a reference to the calling class which Python passes explicitly!

Comment: Hi, thanks :) I accidentally missed the self when I wrote the code's simplification for this question. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is right, *overriding* the `__del__` method means that the base class's `__del__` method is not automatically called anymore (although I don't think a memory leak is likely here). In fact the documentation [explicitly mentions this](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> If a base class has a __del__() method, the derived class’s __del__() method, if any, must explicitly call it to ensure proper deletion of the base class part of the instance.

A code example for this [from the CPython repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e4fe303b8cca525e97d44e80c7e53bdab9dd9187/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L139):

```py
    def __del__(self):
        # ... your cleanup code here ...
        super().__del__()  # call to base class
```

Comment: This only matters if the superclass actually has a `__del__` method, though. Particularly, `object` has no `__del__`.

Comment: Over your example, the class is an inheritor. Why would it work when there's no super class?

Comment: If you try to call `super().__del__` when there is no superclass `__del__` to delegate to, you'll get an AttributeError.

Comment: @NogaK: `super()` is [a mechanism for accessing overridden methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), not a placeholder you're supposed to replace.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica that's why I didn't understand the answer. Consider a case where you add new attributes to the inheritor - they won't be deleted with super().__del__()

Comment: @NogaK Class members are automatically garbage-collected. You really very rarely need to write an explicit `__del__()` method in Python

Comment: @xjcl - then why calling the super method at all?